# Microsoft Graph APIs Reporting InvalidAuthenticationToken as of Yesterday

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

As of yesterday my application using Office 365 accounts are reporting the following error on requests to graph APIs (email, onedrive, etc)

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-11-11T13:27:22",
      "request-id": "f528a476-f882-4d0b-9aab-b5657245e2c0",
      "client-request-id": "f528a476-f882-4d0b-9aab-b5657245e2c0"
    }
  }
}
```

Things still work find using outlook.com accounts... it's just office 365 accounts reporting this error.

I am confused as to how this would just start all of a sudden after working for more than 3 or more years.

I have tried re-registering and getting a new token, refreshing tokens, and still get the same error.

Thank you for any assistance.  I guess I am not sure what else to provide as it's been a standard request token/refresh that's worked for a while and nothing on my end has changed.

Comment: Could you please share the correct requestid and timestamp?

Comment: The are in the response above.  That's the exact error retrieved.

Comment: I tried searching the backend logs but they don't match. Please give me the new Requestid and timestamp please.

Comment: Thank you.  I found the issue on my end.  The token size appears to have been increased to larger than I was expecting.  I should have checked that first.

Comment: Glad to hear that the issue was resolved :)-